# Can't show clock in OSX menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, clock

Recently the clock on my OSX menu bar has disappeared for no apparent reason. I'm using OSX 10.10.5

I try to add it again by going to System Preferences --> Date & Time --> Clock --> Show date and time in menu bar.

When I click on the option box, after about a second it seems to just uncheck itself. No error or warning is provided.

How can I make the clock appear in my menu bar again?

Comment: Have you tried resetting your disk permissions?  I've seen this help with similar strange problems.

Comment: How do I reset disk permissions?

Comment: Mike, here's a support article on how to repair disk permissions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560

Comment: Doing repair disk fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!